# LINQ ExecuteQuery - Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have problem with Executequery:
Error message: "Specified cast is not valid". I tried do:

```
var qq = db.ExecuteQuery<class_search>(query, ddl4, ddl5, ddl1).ToList();
```

But the same error too. I tried in few ways yet. Always is this error or "The query results cannot be enumerated more than once", when I tried do IEnumerable. I read many articles but I don't how do it. What am I doing incorrectly, or missing?

```
public class class_search
{
    public string path_image
    { get; set; }

    public string name_product
    { get; set; }

    public float cost
    { get; set; }
} 

public partial class Search : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();

    string ddl4 = DropDownList4.SelectedItem.Value;
    string ddl5 = DropDownList5.SelectedItem.Value;
    string ddl1 = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;

    string query = "select p.path_image, p.name_product, p.cost from Table1 a, Table2  p, Table3 k where a.column1 = {0} and a.column2 = {1} and k.column2 = {2} and p.IDForeignColumn1 = k.IDcolumn and p.IDForeignColumn2 = a.IDcolumn"

    var qq = db.ExecuteQuery<class_search>(query, ddl4, ddl5, ddl1);

    ListView1.DataSource = qq;
    ListView1.DataBind();
}
```

//I changed code to eng language. Now a.column1, a.column2 and k.column2 are string types.

Comment: where your defining `quote` should that be `query` ?

Comment: Is quote the same thing as query? If not, what is `query`? Maybe it would be easier not to cast anything in ExecuteQuery and just create klasa_wyszukiwania object from fields stored in qq? Please try to avoid Polish language, it may be hard to read for English-speaking readers ;)

Comment: What are the SQL types for `a.budowa`, `a.system_operacyjny`, etc.

Comment: I just edited code and wrote types for a.column etc.

Comment: xarier: I need executequery, because if I will do this code, then I will add more controls and check some conditions.

Comment: May I recommend nonetheless not to use ExecuteQuery. I generally do something like this:
var query = db.Objects;
if (condition1){
query = query.Where(...);
}

Now since this probably won't help you with your problem, could you please be more precise how this is actually running within your class (as you have the code posted above to be directly in the class this is probably not really representative of that you are doing).

Comment: Have you tried running SQLProfiler while this runs, and checked in the query run against the DB and the results returned are as you expect? Some tricky-to-find bugs can be traced that way.

Comment: @user1074089 FYI, the comma-seperated join syntax is not standards compliant. I wonder if that could contribute to the problem. Try something like: select p.path_image, p.name_product, p.cost from Table1 AS a INNER JOIN Table2 AS p ON p.IDForeignColumn2 = a.IDcolumn INNER JOIN Table3 AS k ON p.IDForeignColumn1 = k.IDcolumn where a.column1 = {0} and a.column2 = {1} and k.column2 = {2}

Answer (score 0):

Try `IEnumerable<class_search> qq = db.ExecuteQuery<class_search>(query, ddl4, ddl5, ddl1).ToList();` and see if that helps.

I know it seems like a nitpick but the behavior of var may be an impediment here, so it's worth trying. If that doesn't do it let me know and I'll try to update this answer appropriately.

Also, please update your code sample in the question to show what event method your code is in as one of the commenters suggested.

Answer (score 0):

FLOAT type in SQL is not float in .Net CLR, its the double type. As a matter of fact, the float type isn't mapped to any SQL Type by the LINQ-to-SQL provider. So the sent parameters fail when trying to compare class_search.cost or when trying to create the object class_search.

Solution: change your search_class definition to:

```
public class class_search
{
    public string path_image
    { get; set; }

    public string name_product
    { get; set; }

    public double cost
    { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your main problem caused by incompatibility of between **Clr DateType** and **Sql Db Type**. 
to solve this issue yout must be create a view of sql select command and drag it to your dbml designer.

the linq to sql dbml auto mapper engine decide correctly in selection of target and source type.and use in your code generated POCO class of dragged view in yourdbml.designer.cs file and enjoy it.